# How do I correct my array?

Tags: java

I have made two classes these will be shown below (the one in the main class is incorrect and will not run). I would like to print the array and I would also like to know how to allow the user to enter a number to have the details displayed from the given array position. Another thing is what format should I use for the postcode in my code. Thanks for the help.

```
if(input.matches("S")){

    KeyStroke[] patientsDetails = new KeyStroke[5];
    patientsDetails[0] = new KeyStroke(Alex,8,OX3YUN,2039489);
    patientsDetails[1] = new KeyStroke(John,19,OX4BJO,2434587);
    patientsDetails[2] = new KeyStroke(Nick,42,OX1VYN,2233842);
    patientsDetails[3] = new KeyStroke(Melvin,52,OX2YUD,2432340);
    patientsDetails[3] = new KeyStroke(Gian,27,OX43YUM,2234098);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
         System.out.println("Patient name is: " + patientsDetails[i].nameLable);
         System.out.println("Patients age is: " + patientsDetails[i].howOld);
         System.out.println("Patient postcode is: " + patientsDetails[i].postcode);
         System.out.println("Patients cell phone number is" + patientsDetails[i].cellPhoneNumber);
    }
}
```

The second child class is:

```
public class KeyStroke{
   public int howOld;
   public String postcode;
   public String nameLable;
   public int cellPhoneNumber;

   public KeyStroke(int age, String postcode, String nameLable, int cellPhoneNumber){
       this.nameLable = nameLable;
       this.howOld = age;
       this.postcode = postcode;
       this.cellPhoneNumber = cellPhoneNumber;   
   }
}
```

Comment: you are passing the arguments in the incorrect order.Also, for Strings use `"`

Answer (score 1):

Use " before and after string value, make sure your array index is correct and you are not inserting data on the same index. Also, when passing parameter constructor, make sure the order is same as mentioned in the constructor.

Finally when you are running loop, make sure your loop array index corresponds with your loop running. Here is the code:

```
KeyStroke[] patientsDetails = new KeyStroke[5];
patientsDetails[0] = new KeyStroke(8,"OX3YUN","Alex",2039489);
patientsDetails[1] = new KeyStroke(19,"OX4BJO","John",2434587);
patientsDetails[2] = new KeyStroke(42,"OX1VYN","Nick",2233842);
patientsDetails[3] = new KeyStroke(52,"OX2YUD","Melvin",2432340);
patientsDetails[4] = new KeyStroke(27,"OX43YUM","Gian",2234098);

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    System.out.println("Patient name is: " + patientsDetails[i].nameLable);
    System.out.println("Patients age is: " + patientsDetails[i].howOld);
    System.out.println("Patient postcode is: " + patientsDetails[i].postcode);
    System.out.println("Patients cell phone number is: " + patientsDetails[i].cellPhoneNumber);
}
```

It will give you the desired solution.